# Hibernate Batch Insert Memory Leak

Tags: java, mysql, performance, hibernate, batch-processing

I facing a problem that i can't solve.

I'm doing a batch insert with hibernate, everything is ok with it, its configured as it should, its batching insert, i checked on mysql log to see the instructions, but the problem is, even after i flush the session, it doesn't release the memory, just a little, i used a profile to check and all the memory is being hold by a HashMap, even after i clear this hash map.

Look the code below.

```
long contador = 0;
final int NUMERO_REGISTROS_GRAVAR = 5000;
Map<String, ContatoBean> mapaContatos = new HashMap<>(NUMERO_REGISTROS_GRAVAR);
final Reader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(stream));
final String nomeTemplate = parametros.get("cmpTemplateMailing");
final MailingTemplateBean mailingTemplate = MailingService.getInstance().getMailingTemplate(nomeTemplate);
MailingFactory mailingFactory = new MailingFactory(mailingTemplate);
Session ss = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();

try (CSVParser csvParser = CSVFormat
                               .newFormat(';')
                               .withHeader(mailingFactory.getCabecalho())
                               .withSkipHeaderRecord(true)
                               .parse(inputStreamReader))
{
  Iterator<CSVRecord> iterator = csvParser.iterator();

  MailingBean mailing = new MailingBean();

  mailing.setNmNome(nomeArquivo.substring(0, nomeArquivo.lastIndexOf(".")));
  mailing.setDsDescricao(parametros.get("descricao") != null ? parametros.get("descricao") : "Sem Descrição");
  mailing.setIcAtivo("Sim");
  mailing.setMailingTemplate(mailingTemplate);

  ss.save(mailing);

  while (iterator.hasNext())
  {
    CSVRecord registro = iterator.next();

    String cpf = registro.get(mailingTemplate.getCampoUnicoIdentificador());

    ContatoBean contato = mapaContatos.get(cpf);

    if (contato == null)
    {
      contato = mailingFactory.buildContatoFromTemplate(registro, mailing);
      contador++;

      if (contador >= NUMERO_REGISTROS_GRAVAR)
      {
        contador = 0;
        mapaContatos.clear();
        ss.flush();
        ss.clear();
      }
    }

    mailingFactory.atualizarNumeroContato(registro, contato);

    mapaContatos.put(cpf, contato);

    ss.saveOrUpdate(contato);
  }

  ss.flush();
  ss.clear();
  ss.getTransaction().commit();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  ss.getTransaction().rollback();
  throw new SistemaException(ex);
}
finally
{
  IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStreamReader);
  IOUtils.closeQuietly(stream);
  mapaContatos.clear();
}
```

This is the code that parses a csv file and save some records in the data base.

And this is some screens from the Profiler Sorry for the link, i can't post images due to being new here :(

**Before** i force the GC

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17155314/Before%20GC.png

**After** i force the GC

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17155314/After%20GC.png

As you can see in the graphs, its start to alloc memory and free some memory, but not all the allocated memory.

Important thing, its just using some memory like 200 mb, not much as the App runs in servers with some memory like 32 gb, the problem is, i just started the application, and did a test to gather data, in production the amount of imported data is much more, and it runs out of memory exception with some imports due to not freeing the memory.

Any tips?

My Hibernate.cfg for the batch insert

```
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">5000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.order_inserts">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.order_updates">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
```

I use 5000 for batch size because the import amount of data is like 400k ~ 2kk records, if set a lower value its takes to long to process.

I'm using Hibernate with Mysql in a Java EE application with WildFly 8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you try to commit the transaction for a batch only. Committing a 2M records insert transaction is going to blow-up your undo/redo logs.

Also make sure you don't use [IDENTITY](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-identity-sequence-and-table-sequence-generator/) generators because it simply disables JDBC batching.

Comment: Hi, i'm not using identity, since i'm using mysql and it doesn't support sequence, i choose TABLE as alternative, it's not the best but supports batch.
You suggest that i commit instead of flushing, is that?

Comment: MySQL doesn't use sequences. It uses auto increment, hence identity. But you use table gen so it's fine. Try committing the batch too.

Comment: But if i commit the batch, i won't be able to rollback if i get an error, what you suggest in this scenario?

Comment: It depends on your use case requirements. Do you really want to rollback 2M insert records because of a failed insert? You can keep the ids of all the current batch entries and delete them on any failure, if that's the case.

Comment: I tryed, still the same problem, i commit the transaction and open a new one, but still holding a lot of memory. :(

Comment: In that case, you need a profiler to find the culprit. I recommend you [flight recorder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/mission-control/java-mission-control-1998576.html).

Comment: I'll try that one, i used YourKit but didn't find the problem :s

Comment: Well, long time no more answers, and still the same problem, so i'm commiting for each batch and saving and int array with the primary keys inserted to delete if needed.